# Ease in and out for scrolling between same page links?

Tags: jquery

I am setting up a website with all of the information listed on one page. I've created buttons so that when you click them, the page scrolls to the section of the page you clicked on. Everything works great, except I want the scrolling to ease in and out. Here's the script I have so far:

```
$(function() {
          $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
              var target = $(this.hash);
              target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
              if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                  scrollTop: target.offset().top -25
                }, 1000);
                return false;
              }
            }
          });
        });
```

I just want to add the easeInOutExpo animation but I've been messing with the code for an hour and I'm not the most skilled with JQuery so I can't figure out where to add it in. Could anyone enlighten me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `line 9` you have `}, 1000);`, here you can define your easing animation as such:

```
}, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo');
```

As always you can [check the documentation on animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to get all arguments correct.

*BONUS:* Consider e.preventDefault(); instead of returning false.

Comment: I've tried doing that but when I add that in it stops all the animations and just jumps to whatever section you clicked on

Comment: Could it be something other than the JQuery that is the problem?

Comment: Make sure you have included the jQuery easing library as well, otherwise those animations are undefined. You can find it here: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Comment: Ah that might be the problem. Do I just copy the code from the two links listed under download?

Comment: Include http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js after you include jQuery in your document.

Comment: Got it to work by including another link from that site. Many thanks